# кнопка Edit в Access не работает combobox

Tags: vba, access, visual-basic, ms-access

Есть ряд комбобоксов с зависимостями. Каждый комбобокс в себе несет значения одной таблицы. После всех выборов значений, добавляем их в одну сводную таблицу.

Проблема появилась с кнопкой редактирования, которая должна брать строку из сводной таблицы и помещать значения обратно в комбобоксы.
При моем коде, комбобоксы остаются пустыми. (textbox при этом заполняются)
Кто сталкивался?

```
Private Sub btnEdit_Click()

    'check whether there exists data in list
    If Not (Me.ToolListsub.Form.Recordset.EOF And Me.ToolListsub.Form.Recordset.BOF) Then
        'get data to text box control
        With Me.ToolListsub.Form.Recordset
            Me.cboRoughFinish = .Fields("roughFinish")
            Me.cboApplication = .Fields("application")
            Me.txtDim = .Fields("dim")
            Me.cboNumberTool = .Fields("numberTool")
            Me.cboTool = .Fields("tool")
            Me.cboHolder = ""
            Me.cboCollet = ""
            Me.cboMmaster = ""
            Me.cboShrink = ""
            Me.cboStrshank = ""
            Me.txtH = .Fields("h")
            Me.txtF = .Fields("f")
            Me.txtS = .Fields("s")
            Me.txtOffsetR = .Fields("offsetR")
            Me.txtD = .Fields("d")
            Me.txtToolLife = .Fields("toolLife")
            Me.txtCorNumber = .Fields("corNumber")
            Me.txtPictureSource = .Fields("pictureSource")

           End With
        End If

End Sub
```

Comment: `ComboBox.Text`или `ComboBox.Value` - значение, `ComboBox.List` - список. Если в список поместить строку, ее нужно транспонировать или заполнить `ComboBox.List` в цикле

Comment: Спасибо! Не совсем понятно как это сделать... Если учесть что комбобокс изначально принимает список из таблицы с id, при этом строка id просто не отображается в комбобоксе....

Comment: Как Вы заполняете его изначально?

Comment: Комбобокс заполняется изначально через Table/Query. В комбобокс передается и ID  и само значение. ID я просто не отображаю в комбобоксе.

Comment: Затем после SQL запроса я передаю в другую сводную таблицу результаты из комбобоксов(только значения без ID ). Теперь мне нужно сделать обратный порядок действий....

Comment: Как там в 'Access', не знаю... Но если у '.Fields` можно определить количество ячеек и взять строку в массив (например, массив `аFields`), то цикл в `VBA` такой: `For i = 1 To UBound(a): ComboBox1.AddItem aFields(i):Next i`

Comment: Спасибо большое. Попробую

Comment: В акцессе принцип работы кантролов несколько отличается от MSForms в других приложениях офиса. Вообще любое интерактивное взаимодействие с комбобоксами в акцессе гораздо проще сделать через VBA-код, запрашивая нужные данные SQL-запросами из базы и построчно обрабатывая (добавляя в список значений), нежели сделать это через встроенный функционал.